# PHP Switch using it with Functions

Tags: php, function, switch-statement

I have this switch and I do certain things based on the selection of the action with the switch. Based on my testing, function thats in the switch is not even taking place when the page runs.

I am interested in being able to running the sortby action for now. when I go to the page, switch puts me in the first case but does not run the function.Why? How do I fix it?

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {
        case 'sortby':
            sort_by($_GET['sortby']);
            break;
        case 'add':
            resident_add($_GET['residentID']);
            include('inc/modify/add.php');
            break;
        case 'edit':
            resident_edit($_GET['residentID']);
            include('inc/modify/edit.php');
            break;
        case 'delete':
            resident_delete($_GET['residentID']);
            include('inc/modify/delete.php');
            break;
        case 'search':
            echo "";
            break;
        default:
            resident_default($_GET['sortby']);
    }

function sort_by($sortby) {
    if ($sortby == "last_name") {
        $sort_db_field = "Last Name";
        $sort_order = "ASC";    
    } elseif ($sortby == "lot") {
        $sort_db_field = "Lot"; 
        $sort_order = "ASC";
    } elseif ($sortby == "date_added") {
        $sort_db_field = "No";  
        $sort_order = "DESC";   
    } else {
        include('inc/error.php?error_code=100');
    }
return $sort_db_field;
return $sort_order;
}

$data = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM `residents` ORDER BY `residents`.`".$sort_db_field."` ".$sort_order."") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't run the function? You're not returning/printing from the `sort_by`, so how can you know?

Comment: @rainfromheaven what should I return in this case in sort_by? I forgot I to use functions the most part... @amal $data = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM `residents` ORDER BY `residents`.`".$sort_db_field."` ".$sort_order."") or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: I added this still not working 
 return $sort_db_field;
 return $sort_order;

Comment: Your `mysqli_error()` should have the link inside: `mysqli_error($dbcon);`

Comment: TWO `return`s in a single function ??? this is madness, second one will never run

Comment: I see. how should I accomplish what I need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 return statements in a function, the second one will never be executed.

Declare two variable before your switch:

```
$sort_db_field = "";  
$sort_order = "";  

switch ($_GET['action']) {
    /*snip*/
}
```

Then in the function drop the returns. This function will now set the values in the two variables you declared.

Comment: Only if you use `global` or pass those vars in by reference.